# Sending List<Socket> Clients by Socket

Tags: c#, list, sockets, object, serialization

Im trying to send a List by sockets in C#
by doing this..

```
       client = new List<Socket>();
       Socket.Send(ObjectToByteArray(client));
```

where ObjectToByteArray is

```
 private byte[] ObjectToByteArray(Object obj) /
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return null;
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
```

but im never getting the return byte[] from the method..

Any help? is there another way of sending objects through sockets?
My guess is that the Socket list is never ending since it never stops receiving information. Is there a way to close it and then reopen it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This goal is doomed to failure. I don't know what you mean by "im never getting the return byte[] from the method" (you're saying the `ObjectToByteArray` method never returns?), but it doesn't really matter because the `Socket` class is not serializable.

There's no way it could be in any useful way: serialization is primarily used to either persist some data (e.g. in a file) or to send some data to some other machine. In neither of these scenarios is there any practical way for a `Socket` instance to be converted to bytes and then back to a `Socket` instance.

If you tried to store a `Socket` instance in a file, then if you tried to open that file again, the values in the `Socket` instance would not make any sense. The underlying unmanaged socket handle, the bound address, and perhaps other parts, all no longer have a connection to the actual OS resources they represent.

The same thing is true if you tried to recreate the serialized `Socket` instance on another machine, except even more so, because those values *never* meant anything on that other machine.

So, the answer to this specific question is "you can't, and you shouldn't even try". If you have some broader goal you were trying to achieve and would like help solving that, you should create a new question that is specific about what you're actually trying to do, i.e. what final outcome you want to have.